# Как создать список из функций (+, -, *, /)

Tags: python

Как создать список из функций (+, -, *, /) используя функцию, которая как аргумент принимает имя (текстом) одной из 4-х арифметических операций

1я часть задачи заключалась в том, чтобы написать функцию, которая как аргумент принимает имя (текстом) одной из 4-х арифметических операций (сумма, сложение, вычитание, деление) и возвращает другую функцию,
которая выполняет эту операцию для 2х переменных:

```
def func_factory(operation):
    if operation == 'summ':
        def summ(a, b):
            return a + b

        return summ
    elif operation == 'mul':
        def mul(a, b):
            return a * b

        return mul и т.д.

summation = func_factory('mul')
res = summation(12, 2)
print(res)
```

2я часть. Используя эту функцию нужно создать список из полученных функций (выполняющих арифметические операции) и применить их по очереди к одной и той же паре аргументов

Должно получиться:

```
lst = [summ, mul, subtract, divide]
for func in lst:
    func(x,y)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот решения ваших задач

```
def func_factory(operation):
    if operation == 'summ':
        def summ(a, b):
            return a + b
        return summ
    elif operation == 'mul':
        def mul(a, b):
            return a * b

        return mul
    elif operation == 'subtract':
        def subtract(a, b):
            return a - b

        return subtract
    elif operation == 'divide':
        def divide(a, b):
            return a / b

        return divide
    else:
        raise Exception


x = int(input())
y = int(input())
funcs_names = ['summ', 'mul', 'subtract', 'divide']
lst = [func_factory(i) for i in funcs_names]
for func in lst:
    print(func(x, y))
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Отличное решение!

Comment: @pythonista0801 Как сказать [спасибо](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

**UPD** Данный код работает и я его оставлю как пример того, как это может работать. Но, не используйте данный код в своих проектах и вот почему (согласно `PEP8`):

> Always use a def statement instead of an assignment statement that binds a lambda expression directly to an identifier

> Всегда используйте выражение def, а не присваивание лямбда-выражения к имени

Правильное использование:

```py
def f(x): return 2*x
```

НЕ правильное использование:

```py
f = lambda x: 2*x
```

Коротко: **не присваивайте имена для `lambda` выражений**

Вставлю свое решение, может понравится

```py
def operation(*args):
    func = {
        "minus": lambda a, b : a - b,
        "plus" : lambda a, b : a + b,
        "substract":lambda a, b : a * b,
        "divide":lambda a, b : a / b
    }
    if args:
        for i in args:
            assert i in func.keys()
            return func[i]
    return func
```

Посмотрим на результаты

```py
>>> operation("minus")(10,2) 
8
>>> operation("plus")(10,2)  
12
>>> operation("substract")(10,2) 
20
>>> operation("divide")(10,2)    
5.0
>>> for name, func in f.items(): 
...   func(10,2) 
... 
8
12
20
5.0
```

Ну, и в итоге, что будет если передадим чушь

```py
>>> operation("blabla")(10,2)    
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 10, in operation
AssertionError
```

Что и требовалось ожидать.

Comment: Спасибо за решение! Оочень интересное!

Comment: @pythonista0801 это так, извращение))) `lambda` - это анонимная функция и смыла так использовать нет))) все равно им имена присвоил. Просто захотелось немного анархии на ночь глядя

Answer (score 0):

просто для расширения ассортимента. решение с использованием модуля operator

```
import operator as op

def func(oper):
    funcs_names = {
        '+':  op.__add__,
        '*':  op.__mul__ ,
        '-':  op.__sub__,
        '/':  op.truediv
    }
    try:
        return funcs_names[oper]
    except KeyError:
        raise ValueError('Неверная операция')


print(func('*')(5, 7))  # 35
```