# Написать функцию, которая по оператору вернёт функцию

Tags: python

Написать функцию которая в качестве аргумента принимает одну из следующих строк

```
'+', '-', '*', '**', '/'
```

а возвращает функцию, которая принимает 2 аргумента и возвращает результат математической операции между ними.

Comment: *Как только не пробовал* - приведите в вопросе ваши варианты кода

Comment: "Как только не пробовал" - а можно посмотреть, как все-таки пробовали? Что именно вызывает у вас затруднения?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как создать список из функций (+, -, \*, /)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1282081/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b9)

Answer (score 1):

Если есть питон 3.10, то можно так:

```
def getopf(op):
  match op:
    case "+":    return lambda x, y: x + y
    case "-":    return lambda x, y: x - y
    case "*":    return lambda x, y: x * y
    case "/":    return lambda x, y: x / y
    case "**":   return lambda x, y: x ** y

print(getopf("*")(3, 6))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def func_factory(operation):
    if operation == 'summ':
        def summ(a, b):
            return a + b
        return summ
    elif operation == 'mul':
        def mul(a, b):
            return a * b

        return mul
    elif operation == 'subtract':
        def subtract(a, b):
            return a - b

        return subtract
    elif operation == 'divide':
        def divide(a, b):
            return a / b

        return divide
    else:
        raise Exception


x = int(input())
y = int(input())
funcs_names = ['summ', 'mul', 'subtract', 'divide']
lst = [func_factory(i) for i in funcs_names]
for func in lst:
    print(func(x, y))
```

Источник: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1282087/197602

Comment: Похоже, вы даже гуглить не пробовали)

Comment: Не следует отвечать на вопросы, которые нарушают правила сайта.